# Counting words in a string in JAVA

Tags: java, string, count

Trying to write  a program that will count the words in a string using simple string methods and ran into a "cannot find symbol" error. I know this is because of the "count" variable but I cant think of any other way to do this. Any help appreciated.
By the way the logic i'm using is counting the spaces and then adding 1.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class exam{
   public static void main(String[]args)
   {

      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter");
      String s1= new String(scan.nextLine());

      for(int num1 =0; num1<= s1.length()-1; num1++)
      {

         if(s1.charAt(num1)==' ')
         {
            int count =0;
            count++;
         }

         System.out.println(count+1);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: You need to declare it outside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the `count` variable outside of the `if` condition. Instead of this:

> ```
> if(s1.charAt(num1)==' ')
> {
> int count =0;
> count++;
> }
> ```

Like this:

```
int count =0;
if(s1.charAt(num1)==' ')
{
count++;
}
```

That will solve the "cannot find symbol" error, but your program will still be broken.

To fix, move the declaration outside the `for` loop.

Btw the program is terribly formatted. Use an IDE like IntelliJ or Eclipse to reformat it nicely.

Comment: I genuinely don't know how I didn't think of moving it out of the for loop, thanks for that. Will consider another IDE thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Java 8, you can try lambdas and functional programming. For instance, one way of counting the number of spaces of your string and adding one using lambdas could be:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class stream {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter");
        String s1= new String(scan.nextLine());
        System.out.println(s1.chars().reduce(1, (a, b) -> a + (b == ' ' ? 1 : 0)));
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.